# Connection Issue with Selenium - Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, network-programming, microsoft-edge

I'm using Selenium to automate something in here, and for security manners the program waits at the login page for the user to fill the form and log in to continue, and for some unknown reason, if I wait too long to log in the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10048] Normalmente é permitida apenas uma utilização de cada endereço de soquete (protocolo/endereço de rede/porta)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000020BFC310E48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Normalmente é permitida apenas uma utilização de cada endereço de soquete (protocolo/endereço de rede/porta)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\MyFiles\SMS\sms.py", line 145, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\MyFiles\SMS\sms.py", line 35, in main
    conn.login()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\MyFiles\PSConsultas\PeopleSoft.py", line 23, in login
    while self.driver.execute_script('return document.title') != "Employee-facing registry content":
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\event_firing_webdriver.py", line 88, in execute_script
    return self._dispatch("execute_script", (script, self._driver), "execute_script", unwrapped_args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\event_firing_webdriver.py", line 160, in _dispatch
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\event_firing_webdriver.py", line 157, in _dispatch
    result = getattr(self._driver, d_call)(*d_args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    resp = http.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 72, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 150, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 323, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=58747): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/E2CFB04F-5D8B-4755-A52B-77FA482A4F38/execute (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000020BFC310E48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Normalmente é permitida apenas uma utilização de cada endereço de soquete (protocolo/endereço de rede/porta)',))
```

And those exceptions cause another exceptions, but I think that's the relevant code.

I set up the driver this way:

```
    self.ie = webdriver.Edge(application_path + '\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')
    self.driver = EventFiringWebDriver(self.ie, MyListener())
```

The *MyListener* object does only some implicit waiting, nothing relevant, too.

The error is in Portuguese, but it says *"Usually only one use of each socket address is allowed (protocol / network address / port)"*

The program runs quite fine if you don't take long enough, but that error sometimes happens at random points of the execution of it.

Thanks in advance!

### **EDIT 1**

I put the entire traceback in case it helps, and if it helps too here's the loop that I did to wait for the user to log in, which is where I can guarantee that waiting too long causes de exception:

```
def login(self):    
    url = 'https://somepage.com'

    self.driver.get(url)

    while self.driver.execute_script('return document.title') != "Page Title":
        pass
```

Comment: Check if you've got two different instances of Edge installed on your pc. If yes, then remove one of them.

Comment: I don't think I got it. You mean running at the same time? Because it's an .exe file, and I copied into different places on my computer... But that couldn't be causing it, could it? Anyways, I only call one webdriver running at a time...

Comment: Yes, it is a possibility. It happens with firefox also when there are x86 and x64 versions installed on the same machine, eventhough the other one is not running.

Comment: But I use in different projects, so I end up copying it a lot of times... If I used a shortcut for it, and they all pointed to the original file, maybe it'll work...?

Comment: try that. Not sure unless I see more of the code. Are you using the latest selenium, are you closing your drivers after use?

Comment: Yep. Did everything, checked Selenium version, there is only one MicrosoftWebDriver.exe in my entire computer, but still... If I wait too long to login (and I'm afraid that might happen at any time during the execution, that's why I'm concerned, actually) it raises this weird exception.